# Sharing git repo on NTFS partition between Linux/Windows dualboot

Tags: linux, windows, git, ntfs

I'm developing an (Qt) application which should run under Windows and Linux. So, I want to be able to develop under Windows and Linux, too.

Therefore I have stored my project (as git repo) on a NTFS partition which I mount under Linux (Ubuntu 13.10). To avoid the rights problem of the compiled executable I set the shadow build directory to my home folder under Linux.

This approach work quit good so far. But there are some effects that make me worry: If I stage some changed files (with smartgit), smartgit doesn't reflect that I have stage them. They are still displayed as unstaged

Similar thing when commiting: After the commit, the commited changes are still display as if they where not commit. But in the log I can see they are commited. Closing an reopen the repo "solves" this issues or is a workaround at least.

But I have concerns that I break my repo using it on a NTFS partition under Linux. Or is there no risk that my repo is getting corrupted one day using it that way?

Comment: I am in need of this solution as well. Would save a lot of space in memory instead of having duplicate shared files.

Answer (score 8):

This [answer has been given](https://askubuntu.com/a/876908) by Fco P. on the askubuntu question mirror. This happens because Windows and Linux deal with file permissions differently. Use

```
git config core.filemode false
```

to disable git tracking file permissions and solve this issue.